# Proper way to install debian packages on filesystem extracted on host machine not directly on development board

Tags: ubuntu, debian, customization, package, apt

I am customizing linux filesystem based on ubuntu, the filesystem is extracted on my development machine in which i can install custom binaries, libraries and scripts which is fairly easy enough.

But I need to install debian package directly to extracted filesystem,
for e.g. say test.deb, and its contents are listed below.

```
dpkg -c test.deb
./usr/lib/
./usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
./usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdrm.so.2.4.0
```

with `"cp -r"` this can be copied in filesystem, by doing that how to satisfy extra runtime dependencies like entry for package manager, package cache etc.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to create an ARM debian file system with debbootstrap, chroot into that and add the package you want. This can be done on your developer system even if your developer system is a different architecture like x86 because you can use qemu-user in the ARM chroot to emulate the ARM commands on x86.